# Cómo hacer búsqueda binaria de datos en c++

Tags: c++

tengo que hacer un programa que me permita cargar un archivo y almacenarlo en un arreglo, también debe permitirme solicitar la matrícula de un alumno para buscarla y en caso de que esté el alumno desplegar todos sus datos. El siguiente es el código que ya llevo hecho, pero me marca el error "cannot convert 'Alumno*´to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'bool busquedaBinaria(int*, int)'. Cómo se puede resolver?

Nota: el for de la parte de abajo sólo sirve para imprimir los datos y el while es para leer los datos desde el archivo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> 


using namespace std;

 struct Alumno{

    string matricula;
    string primerApellido;
    string segundoApellido;
    string nombre;

};





bool busquedaBinaria(int[], int);
bool busquedaBinaria(int a[], int buscado){


    int primero = 0;
    int ultimo = 100 - 1;
    bool encontrado = false;


    while (primero <= ultimo and !encontrado){
        int medio = (primero + ultimo)/2;
        if (a[medio] == buscado){
            encontrado = true;
        }
        else if (buscado < a[medio]){
            ultimo = medio - 1;
        }
        else{
            primero = medio + 1;
        }
    }


    return encontrado;
}



int main(){

    Alumno alumnos[100];
    int nAlumnos=0;
    int i=0;
    int n;
    string cadena;
    char cadenaArr[200];

    ifstream entrada("alumnos.txt");  //Se crea la unión al archivo

    while (!entrada.eof()) {

        getline(entrada,cadena); //Se lee la línea completa con espacios y separador
        strcpy(cadenaArr,cadena.c_str()); // strtok necesita char[] no string, por eso se convierte

        alumnos[i].matricula = strtok(cadenaArr, ","); //El primer token
        alumnos[i].nombre = strtok(NULL, ",");         //El segundo token, NULL hace referencia a la misma cadena
        alumnos[i].primerApellido = strtok(NULL,",");  //El tercer token
        alumnos[i].segundoApellido = strtok(NULL,","); //El cuarto token

        i++;
        nAlumnos++;
    }
  entrada.close(); //Se cierra el archivo
  
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  n = 1;
  
  busquedaBinaria(alumnos, n);
  
  
  
  
  
  //Se imprime el arreglo de alumnos para ver que están los datos
  for(int j=0;j<nAlumnos;j++){
    cout << alumnos[j].matricula << "---" << alumnos[j].nombre << "---"
     << alumnos[j].primerApellido << "---" << alumnos[j].segundoApellido << endl;
  }


}
```

Comment: El error es claro. La función espera como primer argumento un puntero a int o un array de int, pero tú la llamas con un array de tipo Alumno. Por otro lado, poner la firma del la función y después la implementación tiene sentido si la implementación va separada, por ejemplo al final del main. Si no, mejor poner sólo la implementación.

Comment: Olvidé decirte que la firma de la función debería de ser algo así: bool busquedaBinaria(Alumno[], int);